# Built a function to search a dictionary using key or value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building an error handler which handles different kinds of errors arranged hierarchically. As part of that, I need a way to figure out what errors to send a recipient based on what their subscription level is. The below function gives me what I want, but it feels a bit crude to me. Please advise if there is a better, more pythonic way of doing this.

`````
alert_levels = {
  "all": {
    "import": ["file", "email"],
    "send": ["tableau", "delivery"]
  }
}



def get_children_if_parent(tag: str, parent_dict: dict) -> list:
    tag_list = []
    for key in parent_dict.keys():
        if type(parent_dict[key]) == dict:
            if key == tag:
                target = ''
            else:
                target = tag
            tag_list.extend(get_children_if_parent(target, parent_dict[key]))
        else:
            if tag == key or tag == '':
                tag_list.extend(parent_dict[key])
            elif tag in parent_dict[key]:
                tag_list.append(tag)
    return tag_list
            

print(get_children_if_parent('send', alert_levels))
# Output: ['tableau', 'delivery']

print(get_children_if_parent('file', alert_levels))
# Output: ['file']

print(get_children_if_parent('import', alert_levels))
# Output: ['file', 'email']

print(get_children_if_parent('delivery', alert_levels))
# Output: ['delivery']

print(get_children_if_parent('all', alert_levels))
# Output: ['file', 'email', 'tableau', 'delivery']
````
`````

Comment: You should use `isinstance` instead of `type`: `if isinstance(val, dict):`. You can also assign `target` using a conditional expression: `target = '' if key == tag else tag`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a few minor suggestions to simplify the code, lighten its visual weight,
or otherwise enhance readability.

**Prefer normal language when feasible**. If a regular word like `tags` is
available and clear, don't complicate things by using something like
`tag_list`.

**If you need a dict's keys and values, iterate via `items()`**.
You use `parent_dict[key]` multiple times. That's not necessary.
Indeed, iterating over a dict via `keys()` is never useful,
because directly iterating over the dict does the same thing.

**Use `isinstance()` when checking a type**. There are special situations when
`type()` is needed, but for garden-variety checks, `isinstance()` is the way to
go.

**Give your special constant a name**. Your are using empty string as a
wildcard. Help your reader out by using a descriptive name to convey your
intent.

```
WILDCARD = ''

def get_children_if_parent(tag, parent_dict):
    tags = []
    for key, val in parent_dict.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            target = WILDCARD if key == tag else tag
            tags.extend(get_children_if_parent(target, val))
        else:
            if tag == key or tag == WILDCARD:
                tags.extend(val)
            elif tag in val:
                tags.append(tag)
    return tags
```

**You could flatten the conditional structure, but I would lean against it**.
Initially, I was going to suggest an if-elif-elif structure to reduce the
indentation. But after considering it, I opted to leave that alone: your current
approach emphasizes the crucial distinction between the dict case (recurse) and
the rest.

**Evaluate remaining awkward names**. I find the function name and
`parent_dict` to be a bit awkward and/or puzzling, but I don't have enough
context about your project to suggest compelling alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and suggestions

Answer (score 5):

*Work in progress*

**Useless accesses to `parent_dict`**

You iterate over the keys of `parent_dict` and then retrieve `parent_dict[key]` in various places. For a start, you could use a variable to do it just once but there are other (better) options.

Indeed, you could iterate over both keys and values in one go:

```
def get_children_if_parent(tag: str, parent_dict: dict) -> list:
    tag_list = []
    for key, val in parent_dict.items():
        if type(val) == dict:
            if key == tag:
                target = ''
            else:
                target = tag
            tag_list.extend(get_children_if_parent(target, val))
        else:
            if tag == key or tag == '':
                tag_list.extend(val)
            elif tag in val:
                tag_list.append(tag)
    return tag_list
```

**Reduce indentation depth with `elif`**

You could write the inside of the loop as:

```
        if type(val) == dict:
            if key == tag:
                target = ''
            else:
                target = tag
            tag_list.extend(get_children_if_parent(target, val))
        elif tag == key or tag == '':
            tag_list.extend(val)
        elif tag in val:
            tag_list.append(tag)
```

*Edit:*

**Smaller functions**

My feeling is that the logic around the empty string makes the logic harder to understand. Also, having an arbitrary value act as a flag may be misleading for the user who may genuinely want to use `""` as a  argument. It may be easier to define a short function handle the case where `key == tag` and `val` is a dict.

We'd get something like:

```
def get_all_children(parent_dict: dict) -> list:
    tag_list = []
    for key, val in parent_dict.items():
        if type(val) == dict:
            tag_list.extend(get_all_children(val))
        else:
            assert type(val) == list
            tag_list.extend(val)
    return tag_list


def get_children_if_parent(tag: str, parent_dict: dict) -> list:
    tag_list = []
    for key, val in parent_dict.items():
        if type(val) == dict:
            if key == tag:
                tag_list.extend(get_all_children(val))
            else:
                tag_list.extend(get_children_if_parent(tag, val))
        else:
            assert type(val) == list
            if tag == key:
                tag_list.extend(val)
            elif tag in val:
                tag_list.append(tag)
    return tag_list
```

*Second edit*

**Relaxing constraints on get_all_children inputs**

By-reading the code above, something appeared to me: in 2 different places, we do the same thing, we get either `get_all_children(val)` or just `val` based on whether `val` is a list.

It could be easier to just accept that `get_all_children` can accept a list a as parameter and the logic becomes:

```
def get_all_children(collection) -> list:
    if type(collection) == list:
        return collection
    assert type(collection) == dict
    tag_list = []
    for key, val in collection.items():
        tag_list.extend(get_all_children(val))
    return tag_list
```

Now, in `get_children_if_parent`, we can handle `key == tag` similarly for different types of input.

We'd get something like:

```
def get_children_if_parent(tag: str, parent_dict: dict) -> list:
    tag_list = []
    for key, val in parent_dict.items():
        if key == tag:
            tag_list.extend(get_all_children(val))
        elif type(val) == dict:
            tag_list.extend(get_children_if_parent(tag, val))
        else:
            assert type(val) == list
            if tag in val:
                tag_list.append(tag)
    return tag_list
```

But then I realized that maybe the same strategy could be applied here: if `get_children_if_parent` accepted both lists and dicts, the implementation may be more straight-forward:

```
def get_children_if_parent(tag: str, collection) -> list:
    if type(collection) == list:
        return [tag] if tag in collection else []
    assert type(collection) == dict
    tag_list = []
    for key, val in collection.items():
        tag_list.extend(get_all_children(val) if key == tag else get_children_if_parent(tag, val))
    return tag_list
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternate way. the empty string is one of the things that made my function feel crude. Replacing that with the get_all_children function adds more code, but feels more streamlined

Comment: @mankand007 I'm glad you like it. I'm added more details to my solutions

Answer (score 2):

**Use proper naming**
The name `get_children_if_parent` is a bad name on two counts.

1. Your function does not return a list of children but all leaf nodes in the tree that have a common ancestor with a given tag
2. The name in ambigious. get_children_if_parent what? What is the condition here on the parent here.

A much better name here is `get_leaf_nodes_of`.

**Separate Concerns** You are performing two tasks here. First you find a node that matches a tag and then starting from that node you list all the children. We can separate this and make the code more readable.

```
def find_value_of_node(tag, dictonary):
    for key, value in dictonary.items():
        if key == tag:
            return value

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return find_value_of_node(tag, value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if tag == item:
                    return item 
        elif value == tag:
            return value

def iterate_over_leaves(node):
    for _, value in node.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from iterate_over_leaves(value)
        else:
            yield value

def list_all_leaves(node):

    if isinstance(node, dict):
        return [leaf for leaf in iterate_over_leaves(node)]
    if isinstance(node, list):
        return [item for item in node]
    return [node]

def get_leaf_nodes_of(tag : str, dictonary : dict) -> list:

    value = find_value_of_node(tag, dictonary)
    
    if value is None:
        return
    
    return list_all_leaves(value)

print(get_leaf_nodes_of('send', alert_levels))
```

**Make your data structure consistent**
Currently, you have a tree where the `leaf - 1` and `leaf` nodes are different from others, aka the `leaf - 1` nodes store children in a list, and `leaf nodes` are strings. This creates a lot of noise in the code. Instead you can have a uniform structure by defining a node as given below.

```
@dataclass
class Alert:
    name : str
    children : List['Alert'] = field(default_factory=List)

alert_levels = Alert(
    "all", [
        Alert(
            "import", [
                Alert("file", []),
                Alert("email", [])
            ]
        ),
        Alert(
            "send", [
                Alert("tableau", []),
                Alert("delivery", [])
            ]
        )
    ]
)

def iterate_over_leaves(node):
    if not node.children:
        yield node

    for child in node.children:
            yield from iterate_over_leaves(child)

def find_node(tag, root):
    if root.name == tag:
        return root
    
    for child in root.children:
        node = find_node(tag, child)
        if node:
            return node
        
    return None

def get_leaf_nodes_of(tag : str, dictonary : dict) -> list:

    node = find_node(tag, dictonary)
    if not node:
        return []

    return [leaf.name for leaf in iterate_over_leaves(node)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I reworked my previous solution.  It may, if your use case supports it be beneficial to flatten the data structure and include an `all` field.

```
from typing import Any

alert_levels = {"import": ["file", "email"], "send": ["tableau", "delivery"]}
alert_levels["all"] = [
    tag for tag_list in alert_levels.values() for tag in tag_list
]


def get_children_if_parent(tag: str, parent_dict: dict[str, Any]) -> list[str]:
    return parent_dict.get(tag, [tag])



assert get_children_if_parent("send", alert_levels) == ["tableau", "delivery"]

assert get_children_if_parent("file", alert_levels) == ["file"]

assert get_children_if_parent("import", alert_levels) == ["file", "email"]

assert get_children_if_parent("all", alert_levels) == ["file", "email", "tableau", "delivery"]
```

If you don't like the idea of modifying the global object you could create your own dict to support the `all` call

Note when you perform the `d[key]` what you are calling under the hood, is the dictionary's `__getitem__` special method.

```py
class AlertLevel(dict[str, list[str]]):
    def __getitem__(self, tag: str) -> list[str]:
        return self.get(tag, [tag])
    
    def get_all(self) -> list[str]:
        return [tag for v in self.values() for tag in v]
    

alert_levels = AlertLevel( {"import": ["file", "email"], "send": ["tableau", "delivery"]})

assert alert_levels["send"] == ["tableau", "delivery"]

assert alert_levels["file"] == ["file"]

assert alert_levels["import"] == ["file", "email"]

assert alert_levels.get_all() == ["file", "email", "tableau", "delivery"]
```

Comment: This is a very different kind of solution. Thank you for this!

Comment: The second example takes more of an OOP approach.  In general, if I'm writing a function that deals with a specific data structure, I try to encapsulate that function as a method of the object.  this data structure would be a dict[str, list[T]]

Comment: I'm building my error handler as a class, and this function is for one of the attributes of the class. I can use it as a different class and use it in my error handler class, but I'm finding two issues with this approach.

1. I can call this with any non-existent value, and it will return me a list with that value instead of returning an empty list.

2. The structure is a bit rigid, and doesn't allow for nested values. e.g. {"import": ["file", "email"], "send": [{"tableau": ["server", "data"]}, "delivery"]}.

Do you have any thoughts on the above issues?

Comment: Well your structure is a bit messy `dict[str, list[str | dict[str, list[str]]]]`, because the contents of your list is either a `dict` or a `str` you will need to have some logic to resolve that. I suggest that you make the contents of the list consistent.  I'm assuming `import` and `send` are the events where the error occurred.  Try something like `dict[Event, dict[Action, list[Targets]]]`